# Magento2 : Notice: Undefined index: id in vendor\/magento\/module-config\/Model\/Config\/Structure\/Element\/Iterator.php on line 63

Tags: magento2

I am unable to find solution of below error. I have tried with disable some modules checked tab, sections in most of modules. kindly help me for this.

```
{"0":"Notice: Undefined index: id in \/var\/www\/html\/example.com\/vendor\/magento\/module-config\/Model\/Config\/Structure\/Element\/Iterator.php
 on line 63","1":"#0
 \/var\/www\/html\/example.com\/vendor\/magento\/module-config\/Model\/Config\/Structure\/Element\/Iterator.php(63):
 Magento\\Framework\\App\\ErrorHandler-    handler(8, 'Undefined
 index...', '\/var\/www\/html\/y...', 63, Array)\n#1
 \/var\/www\/html\/example.com\/vendor\/magento\/module-config\/Model\/Config\/Structure.php(146):
 Magento\\Config\\Model\\Config\\Structure\\Element\\Iterator-    setElements(Array,
 'default')\n#2
 \/var\/www\/html\/example.com\/vendor\/magento\/module-config\/Model\/Config\/Structure.php(209):
 Magento\\Config\\Model\\Config\\Structure-    getTabs()\n#3
 \/var\/www\/html\/example.com\/vendor\/magento\/module-config\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/System\/AbstractConfig.php(60):
 Magento\\Config\\Model\\Config\\Structure-    getFirstSection()\n#4
 \/var\/www\/html\/example.com\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58):
 Magento\\Config\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\System\\AbstractConfig-    dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#5
 \/var\/www\/html\/example.com\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138):
 Magento\\Config\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\System\\Config\\Index\\Interceptor-    ___callParent('dispatch',
 Array)\n#6
 \/var\/www\/html\/example.com\/vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/App\/Action\/Plugin\/Authentication.php(143):
 Magento\\Config\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\System\\Config\\Index\\Interceptor-    Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#7
 \/var\/www\/html\/example.com\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(135):
 Magento\\Backend\\App\\Action\\Plugin\\Authentication-    aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\\Config\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\System\\Config\\Index\\Interceptor),
 Object(Closure), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#8
 \/var\/www\/html\/example.com\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153):
 Magento\\Config\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\System\\Config\\Index\\Interceptor-    Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#9
 \/var\/www\/html\/example.com\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Config\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/System\/Config\/Index\/Interceptor.php(26):
 Magento\\Config\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\System\\Config\\Index\\Interceptor-    ___callPlugins('dispatch',
 Array, NULL)\n#10
 \/var\/www\/html\/example.com\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php(55):
 Magento\\Config\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\System\\Config\\Index\\Interceptor-    dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#11
 \/var\/www\/html\/example.com\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58):
 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController-    dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#12
 \/var\/www\/html\/example.com\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138):
 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor-    ___callParent('dispatch',
 Array)\n#13
 \/var\/www\/html\/example.com\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153):
 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor-    Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#14
 \/var\/www\/html\/example.com\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php(26):
 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor-    ___callPlugins('dispatch',
 Array, Array)\n#15
 \/var\/www\/html\/example.com\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php(135):
 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor-    dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#16
 \/var\/www\/html\/example.com\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php(257):
 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http-    launch()\n#17
 \/var\/www\/html\/example.com\/pub\/index.php(55):
 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap-    run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#18
 {main}","url":"\/admyokkao\/admin\/system_config\/","script_name":"\/index.php"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try disabling all the custom modules and check for the error. If the system doesn't throw any errors, then that means one of `system.xml` file in your custom modules is causing the issue.

Disable all your custom modules by executing the below command. Here replace `VendorName` with the one you are using.

```
php bin/magento module:status | grep [VendorName] | grep -v List | grep -v None | grep -v -e '^$' | xargs php bin/magento module:disable -f
```